# Strip Debug Symbols Xcode build settings

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm

I see that there are several options for stripping debug symbols
-Deployment Postprocessing
-Strip Debug Symbols During Copy
-Strip Linked Product

I want to strip the debug symbols for my release, but not for my beta and debug versions, can someone help me understanding this options?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XCode4, choose your target and go to the "Build Settings" tab. There you can look out for "Strip debug symbols". Notice a small dropdown arrow on the left side, and upon expanding you can choose the what all configuration you want to specify.
On clicking the "+" button next to each configuration, you can also specify various arch+OS settings to further expand your list.
Hope this helps!